# .on("click") wont work on generated td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following table:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="table_tran">
    <thead>
        <th>Transformations</th>

    </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This table is filled with generated tds when a user do something.What i want is when a user click on a generated td to show the text of the td he clicked on.I am using the following javascript code:

```
$("#table_tran td").on("click",function(){
    alert($(this).html())
});
```

This code won't work on generated tds.Any ideas?
If i use this:

```
 <table class="table table-striped" id="table_tran">
        <thead>
            <th>Transformations</th>

        </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr><td>fxfjjf</td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The code will work only for the td "fxfjjf"

Comment: You didn't read the documentation. Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

*As you are creating table cell dynamically.*

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

*change you code to*

```
$("#table_tran").on("click", "td", function(){
    alert($(this).html())
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the td isn't there when you are trying to bind the click event.  So you'll need event delegation.  You were close.

Change

```
$("#table_tran td").on("click",function(){...
```

To

```
$("#table_tran").on("click","td",function(){...
```

This will trigger the event every time your table is clicked.  And will check the "td" argument to see if it was a match, and if so will fire your callback as desired.